# Retrieve a value from python list which contains angular brace

Tags: python, list

While calling wmi from python its returning a list like this :

```
[<_wmi_object: \\My_server\root\virtualization:Msvm_ComputerSystem.CreationClassName="Msvm_ComputerSystem",Name="6B76E537-049A-4AAB-8BCD-F95B2F0F8F42">]
```

How to retrieve the value of 'Name' ?

Comment: You are getting a `wmi` object. What is `WMI`? Is it Windows management Interface? How you are calling this `wmi`?

Comment: DOWN VOTER dare to comment

Comment: @ Abhijit http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html

Comment: @Reuben SO downvotes are anonymous; this is not very appreciative of someone who is trying to help

Comment: I have seen some people loves to down vote without citing the proper cause. The question can be silly but it can help the questioner. I believe the question can be helpful for Abhijit also.

Comment: Abhijit, spajce, lechlukasz, mdm, Stony  what was the reason to down vote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[<_wmi_object: \\My_server\root\virtualization:Msvm_ComputerSystem.CreationClassName="Msvm_ComputerSystem",Name="6B76E537-049A-4AAB-8BCD-F95B2F0F8F42">]`

is probably a list containing a single element,

`<_wmi_object: \\My_server\root\virtualization:Msvm_ComputerSystem.CreationClassName="Msvm_ComputerSystem",Name="6B76E537-049A-4AAB-8BCD-F95B2F0F8F42">`

and you'll have to read the documentation for this object to find out how to extract the name.

Comment: I was doing 

vm = wmi_service.Msvm_ComputerSystem(ElementName='Windows 7 ultimate')

which was returning the above list.

I should do like this: 
for vm in wmi_service.Msvm_ComputerSystem(ElementName='Windows 7 ultimate'):
 print "UUID: ", vm.Name

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
origList  = [<_wmi_object: \\My_server\root\virtualization:Msvm_ComputerSystem.CreationClassName="Msvm_ComputerSystem",Name="6B76E537-049A-4AAB-8BCD-F95B2F0F8F42">, ...]

names = [getattr(rec, 'Name') for rec in origList if hasattr(rec, 'Name')]
```